# Seamless GPS location data transmit between Mobile apps

Tags: android, ios

I know we can store the first mobile GPS data in Database and retrieve from the second device. But doing this every single move seems not efficient.

1. Is there any better way to transfer this data seamlessly?
2. Also, please suggest the best way to store these data to get the history of routes.

Thank you

Comment: I assume by "Database" you mean a cloud database or storage, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So store the data in a cloud NOSQL document-based database such as Firebase's Cloud Firestore or similar (look at MongoDB's offerings too).  A NOSQL database is designed to be very efficient to accept the data.

Also, plan to cache the data locally for a period of time before transmitting it.  Maybe every minute's worth?  Every 10 minute's worth?  Delay for as long as is acceptable for your needs.

Plan to support a retry mechanism for the transmission of the data to the cloud, as mobile devices often lose access to the network.

Cloud Firebase's client SDK handles all of the above with just a few lines of code, and they make it very easy to get set up with a free account in the cloud.  I believe MongoDB will do the same using Realm on the client soon, too. (I currently use both Cloud Firestore and Realm db in my apps).

All of the above SDKs are supported on both iOS and Android, and you can do processing on your GPS data in cloud functions too... even kick the data over to Google Data Studio and plot out too.

As for how best to store the data to then cull out a route history, I suppose it just depends on what your "route history"'s needs are.  At bare minimum, I'd store a timestamp (of the original location fix), latitude, longitude, and horizontalAccuracy. I'd also include a server timestamp of when the data was received by the cloud, as it could be days later... this could help your route history so you can understand if data was injected later for earlier timestamps.

Consider sending the data in clumps (a cached group of GPS readings), rather than merging it into an existing table in the cloud.  It should be faster that way.  You can always later pipe the data from your NOSQL database to an SQL database to organize and filter it.  (e.g. Cloud Firestore -> Bucket -> BigQuery -> Data Studio)

If you'd like to chat further about any of the above, see my profile for how to reach me on Slack.

Comment: Wow !!! This is a perfect answer which draws me to new efficient direction. I am going to try out this. Thanks heaps mate